# How to trace code in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to know that how can I trace java code in eclipse just like turbo c++ where we use f7 key to trace code or we can say to know step by step compiling of code? So which key should I need to use in eclipse to trace java coding?

Comment: F5 to step into or F6 to step over - Set Break point and enter into debug mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the Java code in with "Debug -> Run As... -> ..."

That enables the debugger. You can now set breakpoints in the left margin of the Java editor.

Use the buttons at the top to step into or over methods. If you hover over the buttons, you'll see the associated keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Is this method also works for TestNG suite?

Comment: Yes. TestNG is still a Java program with some conventions to determine what a "test" is.